# "grep" the available space from "df" output

Tags: text-processing, grep, disk-usage

Hello I need to grep the output from df. Sadly awk is not an option (even though its the easy option) here I can only use grep.

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
none                         4         0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                      5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
none                   1981488       444   1981044   0% /run/shm
none                    102400        64    102336   0% /run/user
/dev/sda3            418176236 281033024 137143212  67% /media/mark/7EE21FBAE21F761D
```

So for example I want the $4 column of the line beginning with /dev/sda3

Comment: On what operating system? There are tricks you can do but they depend on your grep implementation. Please _always_ mention your OS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have a version of grep that supports `-P` (perl-compatible regex, PCREs) and `-o` (print only the matching string), you can do

```
df | grep -oP '/sda3.* \K\d+(?=\s+\d+%)'
```

#### Explanation

Here, we match `/sda3`, then as many characters as possible until we find a stretch of numbers (`\d+`) which is followed by one or more spaces (`\s+`), then one or more numbers (`\d+`) and a `%`. The `foo(?=bar)` construct is a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), it allows you to search for the string `foo` only if it is followed by the string `bar`. The `\K` is a PCRE trick that means "discard anything matched up to this point". Combined with `-o`, it lets you use strings that precede your pattern to anchor your match but not print them.

Without `-P`, things are trickier. You would need multiple passes. For example:

```
df | grep -o '/sda3.*%' | grep -Eo '[0-9]+ *[0-9]+%' | grep -Eo '^[0-9]+'
```

#### Explanation

Here, the first `grep` identifies the right line and prints everything up to the `%`. The second prints the longest stretch of numbers before a space and another stretch of numbers ending with `%` and the final one prints the longest stretch of numbers found at the beginning of the line. Since the previous one only printed the free space and the percentage, this is the free space.

If your `grep` doesn't even support `-E`, you could do:

```
df | grep -o '/sda3.*%' | grep -o '[0-9]* *[0-9]*%' | grep -o '[0-9][0-9]* '
```

#### Explanation

Here, we can't use `+` for "one or more" so, for the last `grep`,  we need to specify at least one number, followed by 0 or more (`[0-9][0-9]*`).

---

If you can use other tools of course, things get much easier:

```
df | sed -n '/sda3/{s/  */ /gp}' | cut -d' ' -f4
```

#### Explanation

The `sed` won't print anything (`-n`) unless the current line matches `sda3` (`/sda3/{}`) and, if it does, it replaces all consecutive spaces with a single one, allowing the use of `cut` to print the 4th field.

---

Or

```
df | perl -lne 'm#/sda3.+\s(\d+)\s+\d+%# && print $1'
```

#### Explanation

The `-l` adds a newline to each print call, the `-n` means "read the input line by line" and the `-e` lets you pass a script on the command line. The script itself matches `sda3`, then any stretch of characters up to whitespace followed by one or more numbers (`\s(\d+)`), then whitespace followed by a stretch of numbers ending with `%` (`\s+\d+`). The parentheses capture the part we are interested in which is then printed as `$1`.

---

Or

```
df | tr -s ' ' $'\t' | grep sda3 | cut -f4
```

#### Explanation

Here, we simply use `tr` to convert multiple consecutive spaces to a tab (the default delimiter of `cut`), then `grep` for sda3 and print the 4th field.

Answer (score 7):

*How to use* `grep` *to solve it as you ask is already anwered;*
*This answer is about how to solve the **example** problem - getting a separate value from* `df`:

GNU `df` from `coreutils` has an option to specify the columns shown in the output:

```
$ df --output=avail /dev/sda3
  Avail
9816416
```

Unfortunately, there is no option to suppress the column header - so it needs to be discarded in an extra step, with `tail`:

```
$ df --output=avail /dev/sda3 | tail -n 1
9816416
```

or `grep`, if you prefer:

```
$ df --output=avail /dev/sda3 | grep '[0-9]'
9816416
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your grep version, you can also use `-o` for only and `-E` for extended regex.

So you can use

```
df | grep /dev/sda3 | grep -E -o "[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+[[:digit:]]+%" | grep -E -o ".+\s"
```

This needs the `%` char as an anchor for the first grep. After this you get the first chars until the space with the 2nd grep.

Comment: Nice, +1. Note, however, that this also includes the final space which might not be desired.